# Multiple inclusions of header files

Tags: c++

I have `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` which both include the header file `header.h`.

Later both `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` are included in a `main.cpp`.

This causes error when `main.cpp` is compiled saying that the header file `header.h` has been included twice.

How to solve this ?

Comment: Google on the term "include guard".

Comment: Not the issue, but you shouldn't include `.cpp` files.

Comment: @KillianDS I know. Later I do plan to move the source into the cpp files and include the class definitions in a separate header file.

Comment: Do not wait 'till later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should surround your header files in

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H

// Contents of your file

#endif
```

These are called include guards.

Second point: you shouldn't be including .cpp files, only .h files.

Comment: The header files are from a library. So I cannot add header guards there. What must i do now ?

Comment: Header files not mandatory have .h extentions, so please change your suggestion, it can confuse some novice programers.

Comment: @RitwikG That sounds like the "library" is thorougly broken. My advice: drop that piece of crap and use something that can actually be called a library.

Answer (score 2):

Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). in your headers, for example:

```
// Header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

// code from original header.h

#endif
```

And don't include `.cpp` files in other `.cpp` files. Include the necessary headers only.

**Edit** If the header files come from a 3rd party library, and do not have include guards, I would be very suspect of that library. I would drop it. However, you can make your own headers, including the library header in an include guard:

```
// FixedHeader.h
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

#include "header.h"

#endif
```

Then `#include "FixedHeader.h"`. But I would drop the library, seriously.

Comment: The header files are from a library. So I cannot add header guards there. What must i do now ?

Comment: @RitwikG if they are from a library, they should already have include guards. If they don't, then drop the library, it is no good! Although note that, on Windows at least, include guards can be expressed with `#pragma once` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot modify header file to include guards, there are 3 possible solutions (sorted from the best to worse):

1 Do not use that garbage.
2 Use wrapper my_header.h

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H
#include <header.h>
#endif // MY_HEADER_H
```

include my_header.h instead of header.h in your code

3 Use guards in .cpp file

```
 #ifndef HEADER_H  
 #define HEADER_H  
 #include <header.h>  
 #endif // HEADER_H
```

you have to be consistent though and use the same guards everywhere (that's why it is solution 3)